# Query performance in describing a race's relative finishing positions

Tags: oracle, performance, query-performance, performance-tuning

Is there a faster, and more parsimonious way to do this?

For each race (i.e. 1, 2, and 3), there are many race entries X (horses), some details including it's finishing position, and in the same row the best 3 other entries not including X (transposing relative non aggregate data from other rows into columns).  So say X was came 1st in the race, the best relative finishing position would be 2nd and the next best would be 3rd, but if X's came 2nd, the best relative finishing position would be 1st and the next best would be 3rd.

Note, I've tried putting case statements in joins - but the performance was bad.  There are PKs and indexes on joins.

So here is my skeleton query (the actual query is huge with a lot more inline views in case statements, and > 1 million rows). The driver table is race_entry.. the rownum checks are there to guard against bad data (2 or more horses finishing 1st, who would have thunk).  Many thanks in advance!

DDL and query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c3e0d8

```
    select 
      re.race_code -- (i.e. 1, 2 and 3)
    , r.name as race_name  
    , re.horse_code -- (see entry 'X marks the spot')
    , h.name as horse_name
    , re.position_finishing_code

    -- relative best entries 1 
    , case when re.position_finishing_code = 1 
        then (select bh.horse_code from race_entry bh where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=2  and rownum<=1)
        else (select bh.horse_code from race_entry bh where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=1  and rownum<=1) 
           end as BEST_HORSE_CODE
    , case when re.position_finishing_code = 1  
                then (select  hi.name from race_entry bh join horse hi on bh.horse_code=hi.horse_code where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=2  and rownum<=1) 
            else (select hi.name from race_entry bh join horse hi on bh.horse_code=hi.horse_code where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=1  and rownum<=1) 
      end as BEST_HORSE_NAME
    , case when re.position_finishing_code=1  then (select bh.position_finishing_code from race_entry bh    where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=2  and rownum<=1) 
            else (select bh.position_finishing_code from race_entry bh where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=1  and rownum<=1) 
      end as BEST_HORSE_POSITION
      
    -- relative best entries 2 
    , case when re.position_finishing_code between 1 and 2 
        then (select bh.horse_code from race_entry bh where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=3  and rownum<=1)
        else (select bh.horse_code from race_entry bh where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=2  and rownum<=1) 
           end as BEST_HORSE_CODE_2
    , case when re.position_finishing_code between 1 and 2  
                then (select  hi.name from race_entry bh join horse hi on bh.horse_code=hi.horse_code where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=3  and rownum<=1) 
            else (select hi.name from race_entry bh join horse hi on bh.horse_code=hi.horse_code where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=2  and rownum<=1) 
      end as BEST_HORSE_NAME_2
    , case when re.position_finishing_code between 1 and 2  then (select bh.position_finishing_code from race_entry bh  where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=3  and rownum<=1) 
            else (select bh.position_finishing_code from race_entry bh where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=2  and rownum<=1) 
      end as BEST_HORSE_POSITION_2
      
    -- relative best entries 3 
    , case when re.position_finishing_code between 1 and 3 
        then (select bh.horse_code from race_entry bh where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=4  and rownum<=1)
        else (select bh.horse_code from race_entry bh where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=3  and rownum<=1) 
           end as BEST_HORSE_CODE_3
    , case when re.position_finishing_code between 1 and 3  
                then (select  hi.name from race_entry bh join horse hi on bh.horse_code=hi.horse_code where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=4  and rownum<=1) 
            else (select hi.name from race_entry bh join horse hi on bh.horse_code=hi.horse_code where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=3  and rownum<=1) 
      end as BEST_HORSE_NAME_3
    , case when re.position_finishing_code between 1 and 3  then (select bh.position_finishing_code from race_entry bh  where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=4  and rownum<=1) 
            else (select bh.position_finishing_code from race_entry bh where bh.race_code=re.race_code and bh.position_finishing_code=3  and rownum<=1) 
      end as BEST_HORSE_POSITION_3

from race_entry re
join race r on re.race_code=r.race_code 
join horse h on re.horse_code=h.horse_code
--where re.race_code=1
order by re.race_code, re.position_finishing_code asc
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! and interesting question. Could you please provide your tables, some sample data with various race positions and  your desired result on dbfiddle.uk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Vérace - I've added tables and some data inc various race positions.  got invalid character via dbfiddle - works in sqlfiddle though.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/776a7d/2

Comment: I've updated the input data to include two missing entries for race 2, and two null position_finishing_codes for race 3.
My query assumes that the data is clean and that there always exists all the required entries and position_finishing_codes.  
Perhaps this query needs to use RANK() instead of comparing position_finishing_codes.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c3e0d8

Comment: I've added to your fiddle - trying to point out where I don't understand stuff - [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87d0e/1). Why in the first record is the best horse code 3 (name phar lap) when phar lap came second in the first race? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve exactly!